# Representing historical prices of certain financial instruments

Tags: c#, finance

I have an object which represents historical prices of certain financial instruments as below:

```
 class DailyPrice
        {
            public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
            public double? Price { get; set; }  
        }
```

This needs to be converted into `QuarterlyPrice` objects which will have all daily prices aggregated:

```
class QuarterlyPrice
        {
            public QuarterlyPrice()
            {
                DailyViews = new List<DailyPrice>();
            }
            public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
            public double? Price { get; set; }
            public List<DailyPrice> DailyViews { get; set; }
        }
```

Now I need to aggregate the daily prices into quarterly prices. I already have the logic of finding the quarters given a date range and the aggregation logic is as follows:

```
class Aggregater
        {
            public IEnumerable<QuarterlyPrice> GetQuarterlyAggViews(List<DailyPrice> dailyViews)
            {
                var dates = dailyViews.Where(x => x.Date.HasValue).Select(x => x.Date.Value).ToList();
                var dictionary = dailyViews.ToDictionary(x => x.Date.Value, x => x);

                //Will give me quarterly dates from the last to fist.
                var allQuarters = dates.Last().GetAllQuarters(dates.First());

                foreach (var quarter in allQuarters)
                {
                    var quarterlyPrice = new QuarterlyPrice();
                    var daily = dictionary.Where(x => x.Key <= quarter).Select(lx => lx.Value).ToList();
                    quarterlyPrice.DailyPrice.AddRange(daily);
                    quarterlyPrice.Date = quarter;
                    quarterlyPrice.Price = daily.Sum(x => x.Price);
                    yield return quarterlyPrice;
                }
            }
        }
```

My questions are the following:

1. My daily prices can spawn 10-20 years and there will be as many daily price object. While aggregating them I'm putting them in the dictionary assuming the lookup would be quicker. Is this the correct thing to do? Is there a way to optimize the look up a bit further?
2. How can I write a better aggregation logic for converting daily to quarterly price?

Note: The daily price list is sorted using .NET 4.0.

Comment: A `GroupBy` might be a better option.

Comment: A dictionary only really makes sense if you are going to lookup items *directly* by key, you appear to be doing a range check so in my opinion you aren't gaining anything here. Also, as another side note, you should really be using `decimal` if `Price` is a monetary value.

Comment: you have to touch each price once anyway - so just follow the lists once. But I what I see here ... `double` for prices ... really? Why not some fixed-point number format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a slightly different way of creating your classes?

```
class Quarter
{
    int Year { get; set; }
    List<DailyPrice> Prices { get; set; }
}
class DailyPrice
{
    public DailyPrice(DateTime? date, double? price)
    {
        Date = date;
        Price = price;
        QuarterPeriod = FindOrCreateQuarterObject(this);
    }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public Quarter QuarterPeriod { get; set; }
}
```

As you create your DailyPrice objects, you can add to the pointer list in the appropriate quarter.  That way if you are collecting aggregate data by quarter all you have to do is spin through your quarters, and then do the aggregation on each quarter's list.

It takes a little more time upfront, and a few more pointers, but you'll save time if you plan to do multiple calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean way to do this using Linq. The code below will group by year and quarter, providing an `IEnumerable` of `QuarterlyPrice`.

```
// Test Data
List<DailyPrice> dailyPrices = new List<DailyPrice> {
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 01, 01), Price = 01},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 02, 02), Price = 02},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 03, 03), Price = 03},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 04, 04), Price = 04},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 05, 05), Price = 05},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 06, 06), Price = 06},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 07, 07), Price = 07},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 08, 08), Price = 08},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 09, 09), Price = 09},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 10, 10), Price = 10},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 11, 11), Price = 11},
    new DailyPrice { Date = new DateTime(2014, 12, 12), Price = 12},
};

// Group and Project
var results = dailyPrices.Where(d => d.Date.HasValue)
    .GroupBy(d => new { Year = d.Date.Value.Year, Quarter = ((d.Date.Value.Month - 1) / 3) })
    .Select(g => new QuarterlyPrice {
        DailyViews = g.ToList(),
        Date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, (g.Key.Quarter * 3) + 1, 1),
        Price = g.Sum(d => d.Price)                
    });


// Results
foreach(var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine("{0:d}: {1:C}", result.Date, result.Price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't quarter a function of month and year, so you could do something like this:

```
var quarts = dailyViews.GroupBy(d => "" + (1+(d.Date.Value.Month-1) / 3) + "-" + d.Date.Value.Year)
```

This will give you a group where the Key is "Q-Year" and the items the list of prices.